# Concatenating 3 strings in LC3

Tags: assembly, lc3

I'm starting to learn LC3 but I'm having trouble getting some of the storing concepts right.

How can I store 2 strings/characters in two different addresses that I specify?

For example I want to store **'a' in x1234**, **'b' in x5678**, and **'c' in x9101**, then print out **'letters: abc'** by concatenating the strings stored in specified addresses

Comment: And where do you want to concatenate them?

Comment: @ErikEidt There is no specific location that I want to concatenate them in
Just wanna understand how to store strings in specific registers and print them out together 
I couldn't find many resources that talked about this in LC3

Comment: Ok, if  you want to concatenate them in memory you'll need a location for that, and to copy them one at a time to that location (and add a nul terminator to make it a proper string).  Once that is done you can print the result as a string. However, if you *only* want to concatenate the characters at the console output, then just output them directly from where they are, one at a time, in the order you want them.